# Error when run: $ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/project/> name_project

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I can't install virtualenv with python2.7 on Mac

```
Mac version:
High Sierra 10.13.6

$ python --version
Python 2.7.15

$ which virtualenv
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv

$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 <path/to/new/project/> name_project
env: /Applications/djangostack-1.8.17-0/python/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

I search in directory folders and i have some pythons:

```
1 -> /usr/bin/python2.7
2 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
3 -> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

I don't know how to fix the error.
Help please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `virtualenv` command has been installed by `djangostack`, whatever that is, and `djangostack` has been removed since, leaving a dangling command in your PATH.

Try `which virtualenv` to see what's actually being run.

You can also use `python -m virtualenv --python ...` to directly run your `python` interpreter's `virtualenv` module (providing it's installed); the results are exactly the same.